# How to create a CATransform3D matching another made using setValue:forKey:

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, catransform3d

I tried to create a CATransform3D, but got it wrong. The following code does what I *do want*, using key-values:

```
[_transitionLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:metrics.translationPointsX] 
    forKeyPath:@"sublayerTransform.translation.x"];
[_transitionLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:metrics.radians] 
    forKeyPath:@"sublayerTransform.rotation.y"];
[_transitionLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:metrics.translationPointsZ] 
    forKeyPath:@"sublayerTransform.translation.z"];
```

[image: right]

And here's how I tried to set it up doing CATransform3D:

```
subLayerTransform.m34 = -0.000555;
CATransform3D subLayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, 0);
subLayerTransform = 
    CATransform3DTranslate(subLayerTransform, metrics.translationPointsX, 0, 0);
subLayerTransform = 
    CATransform3DRotate(subLayerTransform, metrics.radians, 0, 1, 0);
subLayerTransform = 
    CATransform3DTranslate(subLayerTransform, 0, 0, metrics.translationPointsZ);
```

[image: wrong]

How can I create the matching transform to the one using the key-paths ?

Comment: Instead of trying to make a single transform expressed as a chain of transforms, try doing exactly what you did before - apply each transform successively directly to the layer.

Comment: How wrong is the code you have?

Comment: @Sulthan It does something approximating what I expected but doesn't look the same as the former example. . I can make comparison videos?

Comment: @Matt - Because I want to put the CATransforms in a CAKeyframeAnimation - is there a way to make a transform just using key-paths? This would work (though I'd still like to know why my attempt at matrix is wrong)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your two screenshots, and assuming that you're going for a rotating cube effect and the two screenshots are taken at slightly different times in the animation, it looks like the top one has perspective on it and the bottom one does not.

Fixing this is a simple matter of editing the .m34 value of the transform, usually to a small value such as 1/500. There is an excellent write up of this [here](http://ronnqvi.st/the-math-behind-transforms/).

Having done that you need to apply the translation steps before the rotation, like so:

```
CATransform3D subLayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, 0);
subLayerTransform.m34 = -0.000555;
subLayerTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(subLayerTransform, _currentMetrics.translationPointsX, 0, _currentMetrics.translationPointsZ);
subLayerTransform = CATransform3DRotate(subLayerTransform, _currentMetrics.radians, 0, 1, 0);
```

I've done something similar but used a container view controller to shift from one to the next. When commenting on your code I thought that I'd used the z anchor point but it turns out that I didn't. Here is the code I use to transition from one view controller to another as if you were rotating a cube. It may be of interest. This is just an extract from the larger method, hopefully I've not missed anything vital.

```
CGRect newFrame = self.containerView.bounds;
UIView *outgoingView = _currentViewController.view;
UIView *incomingView = currentViewController.view;

incomingView.frame = newFrame;

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];

CATransform3D parent = CATransform3DIdentity;
parent.m34 = -0.003;
self.containerView.layer.sublayerTransform = parent;

BOOL rightToLeft = (_currentViewController == [self.viewControllers itemBefore:currentViewController]);

CGFloat inTranslateX = incomingView.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat inRotation = M_PI_2;
CGFloat inAnchorX = 0.0;
if (!rightToLeft)
{
    inTranslateX = -inTranslateX;
    inRotation = -inRotation;
    inAnchorX = 1.0;
}


CATransform3D inT = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(inTranslateX, 0.0, 0.0);
inT = CATransform3DRotate(inT, inRotation, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
CGRect previousFrame = incomingView.frame;
incomingView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(inAnchorX, 0.5);
incomingView.frame = previousFrame;
incomingView.layer.transform = inT;
incomingView.hidden = NO;

CGFloat outTranslateX = -outgoingView.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat outRotation = -M_PI_2;
CGFloat outAnchorX = 1.0;
if (!rightToLeft)
{
    outTranslateX = -outTranslateX;
    outRotation = -outRotation;
    outAnchorX = 0.0;
}

CATransform3D outT = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(outTranslateX, 0.0, 0.0);
outT = CATransform3DRotate(outT, outRotation, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
CGRect outgoingFrame = outgoingView.frame;
outgoingView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(outAnchorX, 0.5);
outgoingView.frame = outgoingFrame;
[CATransaction commit];

[self transitionFromViewController:_currentViewController
                  toViewController:currentViewController
                          duration:0.4
                           options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                        animations:^{
                            outgoingView.layer.transform = outT;
                            incomingView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                        }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            _currentViewController = currentViewController;
                            outgoingView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                            self.imageView.image = currentViewController.tabBarItem.image;
                            self.viewSelector.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                        }];
```

For experimenting with 3D transforms, I have created a little demo app that allows you to build up a stack of transforms and see the effects. It's available on [GitHub](https://github.com/jrturton/3DTransformFun), and introduced [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/12/17/visual-tool-for-catransform3d/).

Comment: I've set the perspective matrix (is that the correct term?) and it looks much better. . . but something is still not right. . it folds into the middle of the screen, whereas the original folds into the edge. . . is this something you could help with too? What other code would you like to see?

Comment: Basically enough so I can try and reproduce both effects here.

Comment: I've added the code that sets up the layer being presented. . . Pass in the views. . The sublayer transform gets set during dragging. . This should be enough - failing that I can show you the whole project (privately - it won't fit in Stack Overflow).

Comment: Hmmm. I've done some rotating cube effects myself with layers and I found it a lot simpler to adjust the Z anchor point of each facet, then all you have to do is rotate the master layer. I'm away from my mac right now but I'll post the code when I get back. It won't answer your question, but may represent a better way of doing what you want.

Comment: I turned out I needed to apply the translation before rotation. . I've edited you answer to provide the final step. . . thanks for setting me on the right path with perspective.

Comment: Oh right, well done! Do you still want the other code or are you happy now?

Comment: Turns out I didn't use the z anchor point. However I've included the code anyway.